# react-native run-android is not working, Unable to load script from assets, Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device

Tags: android, react-native

Steps to run app in android device: 
 1. cd (project directory)
 2. react-native run-android

[attached screenshot issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHwov.png)

for solving this issue, i used below mentioned commands:

```
1.(in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
2. react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

after that, i faced the issue "Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device", screenshot attached. please check it.
[issue screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgSGp.png)

Comment: Check the updated answer @jasspatel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `npm cache clear`

If it's not working try this command.

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: which command used for increase the inotify limit for permanently  in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

try

```
1. cd(directory)
2. cd android
3. gradlew clean
4. cd ..
5. react-native run-android`
```

Comment: This answer does not address the question posed.